# Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am trying to convert a react application written in the js to ts.
I have a history file
history.ts

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

export default history;
```

In my App.tsx

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import history from "../src/history";

    <Router history={history}>
    ...
    </Router>
```

This gives me an error

[image]

```
Property 'history' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<BrowserRouter> & Readonly<BrowserRouterProps> & Readonly<...>'.
```

What does this mean?

How do I fix this error?

Any help!

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: Did this code work before converting to typescript?

Comment: `Browserrouter` doesn't contain any `history` prop assuming the documentation https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter. And that's why typescript is complaining, because `history` doesn't exist on types used by `Browserrouter`. It was working before because standard React doesn't complain about props that are not used